# delete folders based on name as date in mm/dd/yy in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to delete all directories apart from the current date's directory.
directory names are taken as date in this MM-DD-YY format 
so directory name is

10-12-17

10-11-17

10-10-17
..etc

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Hello World!

    one_day=$(date -d "1 days ago" +%m%d%y)
    for f in [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]; do
    [ -d "$f" ] || continue
    (( $f < $one_day )) &&  sudo rm -rf "$f"
    done
```

While running my script I am getting the following error:

```
./script.sh: line 9: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")

./script.sh: line 9: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

Comment: Have you accepted the good news of ISO8601 into your heart today? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: **s=$(date +%m-%d-%y); mv $s .$s; rm -rf [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]; mv .$s $s** #why not just do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to check an inequality between "11-10-17" and "111017" (one is an int and the other is a string). Bash will let you check for a string inequality using **!=**

```
#!/bin/bash

one_day=$(date -d "1 days ago" +%m-%d-%y)
for f in [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]; do
  [ -d "$f" ] || continue
  [ "$f" != "$one_day" ] && sudo rm -rf "$f" && echo "$f" && continue
  [ "$f" == "$one_day" ] && echo "Leaving $f"
done
```

Comment: ./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Comment: unable to delete all folders. script is only capable enough to delete few. getting below mentioned error for folders like 10-08-17, 10-08-17, 09-30-17.                                                                                               
 ./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Comment: ./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
./script.sh: line 6: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
./script.sh: line 7: ((: 10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Comment: After testing with: **for f in {0..1}{0..9}-{0..3}{0..9}-{0..9}{0..0}; do mkdir "$f"; done** I found my error. I've fixed the conditional by changing (( foo != bar )) to [ foo != bar ].  Try now.

Comment: **for f in $(seq 100); do mkdir $(date -d "$f days ago" +%m-%d-%y); done** might be a better way to create a unit test for this, (and possibly a better way to iterate dates).